# Superset dev server not reflecting changes

Tags: docker, apache-superset

After cloning the official GitHub repo of Superset I'm run `docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up`
after that `cd superset-frontend && npm run dev-server`
I'm able to see running project on the 9000 port
But If I'm making any changes I dot't see any difference.

What I'm doing wrong to start dev environment?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to edit any of the backend projects, have you tried running them with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up` instead of `docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up`? And if you're trying to edit the project from the `superset-frontend` directory, have you tried running it with `npm run dev` instead? I see that `npm run dev` runs [a script](https://github.com/apache-superset/incubator-superset/blob/master/superset-frontend/package.json#L46) with the `--watch` flag, so that sounds like what you're looking for.